# GStreamer gst_element_factory_make fails

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I'm trying out a GStreamer test application, but at runtime the following line fails:

```
demuxer = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux", "ogg-demuxer"); // returns NULL
```

I am using MacOSX and installed GStreamer, libogg and vorbis-tools through MacPorts. So I don't see why it fails.

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

**EDIT: SOLVED!**

The problem was that I needed to install the autodetect plugin from the gst-plugins-good package.

Here's a list of actions that made it work:

Remove the MacPorts installation:

`sudo port uninstall gstreamer`

Add the following line to ~/.profile

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

Download gstreamer, gstreamer-plugins-base and gstreamer-plugins-good sources.

Build and install gstreamer (./configure, make, make install)

Build and install gstreamer-plugins-base (./configure, make, make install)

And for gstreamer-plugins-good I only built the autodetect package because building all resulted in errors for some plugins that I don't need or care about now. I did it like this:

```
./configure
cd gst/autodetect/
make
sudo make install
```

Right now the program builds and runs. I don't seem to be getting any audio output however :( but that's another issue.

Comment: Have you tried passing `NULL` as the second argument (which should generate a unique name for you)?

Comment: @Matthew Murdoch: just tried that, but the the function still returns NULL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading `gstelementfactory.c` (GStreamer version 0.10.25) line 463 (`gst_element_factory_make` function definition), there are three errors which cause a `NULL` return:

1. The first argument ('factoryname') is `NULL` (obviously OK in your code)
2. The named element factory could not be found (the function `gst_element_factory_find` returned `NULL`)
3. The element instance could not created (the function `gst_element_Factory_create` returned `NULL`)

The code performs substantial logging so if you are able to turn this on then you may get further hints as to the underlying problem.

To check that the oggdemux plugin is configured correctly, try running:

```
gst-inspect oggdemux
```

If this doesn't return a result, try using `gst-register` to register it.

Comment: gst-inspect oggdemux => No such element or plugin 'oggdemux'.

How can I install this plugin? In the docs I can find overviews of existing plugins, but I haven't found any instructions on how to get them...

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's going on. The MacPorts probably didn't install ogg support along. 

http://gstreamer.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-missing-plug-in

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ubuntu system just do as follows

sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-*

this will solve the problem.