# Gstreamer : gst_element_factory_make() : always fail and return NULL : Qt5

Tags: windows, qt5, gstreamer

My problem is, I cannot create Gstreamer element.
I am creating `Gstreamer` project using `Qt 5.2.1`

**What I am doing :**

`gst_init( NULL, NULL );`

`GstElement *m_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline1");`

`GstElement *m_rtspSrc   = gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc", "MyRtspSrc");`

But **`gst_element_factory_make`** always return **`NULL`**.

**What I have verified :**

1. Checked if shared object is in $(libdir)/gstreamer-0.10/.  (It is there).
2. `gst-inspect-0.10 rtspsrc`.  (Its gives details of the plugin).
3. gst-launch-0.10 fakesrc ! my_all_plugin ! fakesink  (Its works fine).

**I have also tried alternative option :**

`GstElementFactory *factory = gst_element_factory_find ("rtspsrc");
 if(factory)
      GstElement *m_rtspSrc = gst_element_factory_create (factory, "MyRtspSrc");`

But, **`gst_element_factory_find`** can not find **`rtspsrc`**.

Please help me out from this problem.

I have also google it. But can not find any solution.
I have refer few StackOverflow articles too.

Like [GStreamer gst_element_factory_make fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714168/gstreamer-gst-element-factory-make-fails) and many more, but still have the issue.

Many many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to make a different element and see if that works, e.g.:

```
gst_element_factory_make("fakesrc", NULL);
```

If that also fails then it is likely your environment is not set up correctly. You can try setting the environment variable `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` to the directory containing your gstreamer plugins.

Comment: Thanks man, I just need to add `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` to environment variable. and its work smoothly...:)