# linux gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", NULL) fails on qt5

Tags: linux, qt5, gstreamer, rtsp

My problem is, why does `gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", NULL)` fails every times? I use Qt5 on Ubuntu 14.04. 
I tried `gst_element_factory_find ("rtspsrc")` with success, 
I also tried

- gst-ispect rtspsrc
- gst-inspect-0.10 rtspsrc
- gst-inspect-1.0 rtspsrc

and all successfully

here are link I found 
[on tiku.io](http://tiku.io/questions/4865332/gstreamer-gst-element-factory-make-always-fail-and-return-null-qt5), [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878125/gstreamer-gst-element-factory-make-always-fail-and-return-null-qt5), on [quabr.com](http://quabr.com/22878125/gstreamer-gst-element-factory-make-always-fail-and-return-null-qt5) and I tried to follow instructions, but have the same error:

> GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered: assertion
>   'GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed.

The error occur only when it is time to execute `gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", NULL)`.

I tried to create (successfully)  )

```
gst_element_factory_make ("uridecodebin", NULL)
gst_element_factory_make ("fakesrc", NULL)
gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", NULL)
```

and I got no error.

here is my .pro file content:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig

PKGCONFIG += \
    gstreamer-0.10 \ 
    gstreamer-base-0.10 \
    gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 \
    gstreamer-audio-0.10 \
    gstreamer-video-0.10 \
    gstreamer-app-0.10 \
    gstreamer-rtsp-0.10 \
    gstreamer-rtp-0.10 

CONFIG   -= app_bundle

LIBS += -pthread \
        -lgstrtsp-0.10 \
        -lgstrtp-0.10 \
        -lgstreamer-0.10 \
        -lgstsdp-0.10 \
        -lgobject-2.0 \
        -lgmodule-2.0 \
        -lgthread-2.0 \
        -lxml2 \
        -lglib-2.0


QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fpermissive
```

but my problem still there.
Any help would be apprecied.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the setup code that's present before the call to gst_element_factory_make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours digging my head, I finally found the answer.
it was not about rtspsrc.

in fact, I had to use gstreamer-0.10, and I tried to create avdec_h264 element with that version, instead of gstreamer-1.0.

But I finally move to ffdec_h264, wich is an element of gstreamer-0.10, and ... My program now runs like a charm.

```
gst_element_factory_make ("avdec_h264", NULL) // gave me the error with gstreame-0.10
gst_element_factory_make ("ffdec_h264", NULL) //  Right element to use with gstreamer-0.10
```

Thanks mpr.